# Upgrade 9.04 to laest version

Tags: upgrade

Currently I'm using ubuntu 9.04. I need to update this to a recent version 12.04, 12.10 or 13.04? Is this possible? Can someone point me to a instruction page to do this?

Comment: 9.04 has been unsupported ( no longer getting security updates ) for nearly two years.  You need to nuke the machine and reinstall a supported release, and stay up to date.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have windows 7 also in this machine. Can you give some instruction to do what you suggested? I don't have much experience in installing ubuntu.

Comment: If you don't want to reinstall from scratch, you can try [this method](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release) to facilitate upgrading to each subsequent version. That is, enabling `old-releases` repositories as required (see the answers to that question), you can upgrade from 9.04 to 9.10 to 10.04. 10.04 is an LTS release so you can upgrade from it to 12.04, then (if you want it) to 12.10, then (if you want it) to 13.04. As you can see by the number of upgrades listed, @psusi's method is usually better for such an old release.

Answer (score 0):

## How to (fresh) install ubuntu.

1. Backup all your files first. Everything on your computer will be deleted in step 3.
2. Go to http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop and download an Ubuntu ISO.
3. Create an Ubuntu bootable device (USB or CD) using the instructions on the link above.
4. Connect your bootable device with the PC you want to reinstall and follow the instructions on your screen.